# Script to get Windows 7 backup status of multiple client computers and send email if one fails

Tags: powershell, windows-7, backup

I have looked around and not found anything about remotely checking Windows 7 backup status.

We have Windows 2008 R2 SBS running our domain with 5 Windows 7 client computers. Each client computer is backing up to a NAS (some programs we have are a huge pain to re-install if a hard drive dies, so we have a system image of each). I would like to run a PowerShell script that checks each client computer for a successful backup and if one has failed, send an email.

What I need help with the most is the part to query each computer for backup status.

Comment: How are you backing up computers? What's success criteria?

Comment: we are using windows backup. i am not sure what success criteria exactly, that is part of my question. but to clarify maybe. i need the script to check and see if the back up of each computer was successful. and if not, to send an email.

Comment: So, do you have scheduled tasks that are running the backup jobs? If so, do they all have the same name? In other words, would it be possible to use a single schtasks /query /tn backup_job_name to get status info?

Comment: yes, looks like the backup and restore in control panel makes a scheduled task, makes sense. so what exactly would i do with    schtasks /query /tn automaticbackup. what is the cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many way you can approach this problem. Here is one way:
You can schedule a job on each computer that runs a script which checks the status code of the backup job and if it detects failure send an email.

Now? How do you get the task results? You might use something like this (not tested)

```
$s = New-Object -com Schedule.Service
$s.connect
$au = $s.getfolder('').gettasks(0) | where {$_.name -match 'automaticbackup'}
if ( $au.LastTaskResult -ne 0) {
   ##send email
}
```

Depending on the version of the PowerShell you can, for example, use 'send-email' cmdlet.
Hope this helps get you started.